# Notify screen reader a page changed

Tags: javascript, wai-aria, accessibility

I have a single page application who's managing URLs and page reload.

I was wondering how I can notify a screen reader that the page have been completely reloaded?

The page reload is triggered when clicking an `<a>` tag, and a `<div>` inside body is refreshed (the link clicked and the section of the page where the user is is deleted.

Comment: I think this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619186/tell-screen-reader-that-page-has-changed-in-backbone-angular-single-page-app/18631501#18631501

Comment: @AlastairC what a great answer.