# Developing a full public facing enterprise app with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, angular-ui-bootstrap, isis

Good day All, 
I am working on a public facing web app, which is work in progres, the front-end is 100% based on AngularJS, UIBootstrap, CSS, HTML. So, we have the user form-action invoking restful WEB service using the $resource service and injecting JSON Object into different form control or HTML DOM. Also, things like shopping checkout and basket CRUD operation will be done via service invocation using AngularJS.
But, I am getting concerned with accessibility issues with visually impaired, Java scrip disabled browsers etc

Please, I need practical ideas, challenges and solutions from you gurus and enthusiasts out there. The post I saw regarding this is dated and things have probably moved on in resolving accessibility issues ..... Thanks for your input .

Comment: Practical idea: Read [How to Ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular will not work in a JavaScript disabled environment. This cannot be worked around and if this is a requirement for you I would not suggest using Angular. However, you can make your web pages more screen reader friendly with good use of semantic [aria enabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/) HTML.

Semantic HTML means to layout your DOM in a logical way. Tables are for data. Lists are lists. Forms are in the appropriate form tags. An example: you don't want to use a table element to do web page layout as that's confusing. Is it a real table with data or a layout?

Aria is a series of tags and attributes that screen readers use to communicate more effectively with the end user. It allows you to be more expressive in your raw HTML to users of screen readers without having to change much about your page structure.

Similar question:

[What are the accessibility implications of using a framework like angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853183/what-are-the-accessibility-implications-of-using-a-framework-like-angularjs)